# How to pass PNG image data directly to SDL?

Tags: c++, c, image, sdl2, png

Well passing just external PNG to SDL is very easy with the SDL_image library. I have a class that does just that. The code looks like the following:

```
SDL_Surface* Texture::LoadImg(const char *filename) {
    SDL_Surface* Image = IMG_Load(filename);
    if (Image == NULL ) {
        printf("Unable to load picture%s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return NULL;
    }
    return Image;
}
```

Later on I can just call it with

```
//some code
SDL_Texture* Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer,LoadImg(filename));
//some code
```

But I don't have just a PNG file. I have a binary file that consist of many PNG files inside. Basically I combine binary(PNG) files into one larger file. Later on I just open that binary file and load pictures into memory from one single file. So now I have an array of vectors or pointers or any other types (depending how you read the binary file). Now I need to pass this from memory into SDL or SDL_image to load it as texture. How would I pass already loaded PNG (binary) data into SDL to use as an `SDL_Texture`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SDL uses a type called [`SDL_RWops`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops) for this purpose. This is essentially a wrapper around a stream. When you call a function like [`IMG_Load(filename)`](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_image/SDL_image_11.html#SEC11) it is just a small wrapper around [`IMG_Load_RW(ops)`](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_image/SDL_image_24.html#SEC24) which constructs the `ops` using [`SDL_RWFromFile`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromFile). You can create an [`SDL_RWops`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops) yourself (it's just a struct with some function pointers) if you have a custom stream type.

There's also a helper function [`SDL_RWFromMem`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromMem) which creates an [`SDL_RWops`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops) for manipulating bytes in memory like they are a file, which is probably what you're looking for in conjunction with [`IMG_Load_RW`](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_image/SDL_image_24.html#SEC24).

Answer (score 0):

[MNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-image_Network_Graphics) might be worth looking into which basically specifies a single file containing multiple images with PNG like compression.
And there are a couple of libraries for assigning the [MNG components to SDL](https://github.com/dulsi/SDL_mng) textures.

Comment: Too bad that the MNG format never really caught on. Standard practice in the gamedev industry is to bundle multiple PNG textures in a ZIP archive or some other standardized or inhouse-developed container format.